# connect to a device, from behind router, that connected to modem

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, remote-desktop, localhost

Network Diagram Picture:

[image: Network Diagram Picture]

Is it possible to connect from "Android Device" to "Desktop PC",
or from "Laptop" to "Desktop PC" on the local network without internet, for using a remote desktop connection or lanhost?

Comment: check to see if you wifi router has a setting called Client Isolation or AP Isolation enabled. if so, disable it. based on your diagram, devices in the wifi network should be able to reach devices in the ethernet network (though not the other way around) so its likely that the wifi router is filtering traffic.

Comment: when i disabled it, is it gonna use ip's like 192.... or sticks with same right now (10.0...) ?
in the other hand router limits bandwith on wifi devices is it important on this situation ?

Comment: and i cant find that (Client Isolation or AP Isolation) setting.

Comment: Isolation is used to keep people in coffee shops from hacking eachother. it just prevents clients on the same network from seeing eachother. isolation settings may or may not be the issue, but the first thing I would check. The only think that could make your clients change IPs is if you put the Wifi router in Bridge mode (which would probably help the reachability issue, if you don't actually want to have two LANs, so consider it if that is the case).

Comment: Probably just a missing route. @samad could you update the question with the output of `route print`?

Comment: @mashuptwice, i think mod is edited the picture is it good now ?
(or i misunderstood you ?)

Comment: @Frank Thomas, i will try the bridge mode, but while in two LAN modes isnt it reachable ?

Comment: so wifi routers generally use NAT, a technology that hides the devices on the LAN from devices on the WAN. with a standard consumer grade wifi router, your LAN clients can connect to systems outside the LAN, but systems on the WAN side of the router cannot connect to systems inside the LAN, without port forwarding. putting the router in bridge mode just puts all your devices in a single LAN, so they can all see each other.

Comment: that was a goergeus explanation thanks for that NAT and port forward thing. I just get it now. i just remember now, tried all in one Lan (bridge) mode before, but (i cant remember) for some reason i changed it to this mode.
I just wondered if it can be done or not.

Comment: is port forwading does the job without connecting to internet ?
to give an example RDP connection on windows TCP port 3389 and UDP port 3389 opened on router and "Laptop" i mean its 10.0.0.5:3389 ports are open, how to connect it from "Desktop" ?

Comment: port forwarding is just a way to accept incoming connections from one side of a NAT, so it doesn't really have anything to do with your Internet gateway, though when people talk about it, port forwarding is most often used to allow outside connections to the internet. since the router is inside your network though, thats not the case this time. yes, you could create a port forwarding rule for TCP\3389 directing it to the laptop if you wanted.

Comment: It can be done with static routing. On your modem, you would configure that 10.0.0.0/24 goes to 192.168.1.100 However, unless you have a good reason to go with your current setup of seperate networks and 2 routers (the modem is a router too), it would be better to reconfigure your wifi router to be an Access Point. This would put all your devices in the 192.168.1.x range and get rid of the double NAT which has its own issues too.

Comment: thanks for helpings all of you.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:** (Frank Thomas)

port forwarding is just a way to accept incoming connections from one side of a NAT, so it doesn't really have anything to do with your Internet gateway, though when people talk about it, port forwarding is most often used to allow outside connections to the internet. since the router is inside your network though, thats not the case this time. yes, you could create a port forwarding rule for TCP\3389 directing it to the laptop if you wanted.

**Solution 2:** (Silbee)

It can be done with static routing. On your modem, you would configure that 10.0.0.0/24 goes to 192.168.1.100 However, unless you have a good reason to go with your current setup of seperate networks and 2 routers (the modem is a router too), it would be better to reconfigure your wifi router to be an Access Point. This would put all your devices in the 192.168.1.x range and get rid of the double NAT which has its own issues too.